# Как активировать js скрипт не заходя на сайт?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Мне нужно, чтобы определенный скрипт запускался и выполнялся на определенной странице не заходя на неё. Можно ли это как то сделать

Comment: зайти кто-то должен, если на серверной стороне скрипт, то смотрите в сторону cron

Comment: Надо чтобы на клиентской части раз в день нажималась кнопка

Comment: вы можете действительно запускать на сервере скрипт фоновым процессом, а изменения в базе данных держать

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Чтобы раз в день на клиентской части нажималась кнопка, вам необходимо глубже изучить, что такое клиент, что такое сервер, как выполняются запросы, что может клиент, а что может сервер.

Если коротко на ваш вопрос:

- сервер `НЕ МОЖЕТ` нажать кнопку на клиенте, тк для сервера кнопка - кусочек html/js-кода, который он отдаст клиенту, а тот его отрисует на мониторе пользователя в виде кнопки и добавит функционал нажатия
- сервер `МОЖЕТ` выполнить скрипт, на который ссылается контроллер этой кнопки

То есть, нажать кнопку "Удалить товар" на сервере вы не можете, но залезть в бд и пометить его удалённым вы можете, и для этого вам никоим образом не нужна кнопка (только если это не `Enter` на клавиатуре :) ).

Что вам нужно? Вам нужно раз в день вызывать скрипт, который вызывется при запросе от кнопки. Как вызывать скрипт на js, я думаю, вы знаете, а чтобы исполнять это раз в день, вам нужно загуглить `js cron` и по первым нескольким ответам открываются готовые библиотеки для этого действия (либо поискать `js rabbitmq`, но это менее правильный конкретно для вашей задачи путь, а ещё там надо разворачивать RabbitMQ, что может оказаться нелёгкой задачей).

Comment: Гммм.. Но ведь можно "зайти" на сайт через headless браузер и нажать кнопку.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko можно зайти на сайт через консольный браузер, можно через селениум открывать окошко, можно слать запрос со всеми данными курлом, есть множество способов. Но если вам нужно выйти из вима, не будете же вы перезагружать компьютер?

Comment: Так вы же черным по белому\белым по черному пишите, что *сервер НЕ МОЖЕТ нажать кнопку на клиенте*. Зачем? Ведь сервер может это сделать)

Comment: Чёрным по серому, там с косыми кавычками. Да, я это написал и даже выделил, тк если человек не особо понимает, что есть сервер и что представляет кнопочка, то нужно указать верную дорогу, а не просто ответить на вопрос. Накидывать инфу про консольные браузеры здесь - советовать магазин с линзами из неразбивающегося стекла.